# Using managed identities in queue triggers in azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, managed

I'd like to use managed identities instead of username and password configured in the storage account connection. I only see the option to configure the queue trigger with a connection string, but can't add a managed identity to avoid secrets to be configured.
Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain it is not possible as of now, you can only use managed identities when the function runs to access resources, not for the trigger. I cannot dig up a proof for that right now, saw it on some GH issue.

Comment: Yeah this is my guess as well. It'd be possible if the connection string allowed to define "UseManagedIdentity=True" or something.

Comment: yeah, similar to what appservice does with keyvault reference

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using the Microsoft Azure Function Extension Libraries, e.g. "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs".

Exampleconnection configuration for managed identities:

```
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount": "",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__queueServiceUri": "https://mytestfa.queue.core.windows.net/",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__credential": "managedidentity"
```

And reference the connection in the function trigger like this:

```
 [Function("ProcessUserData")]
 public async Task ProcessUserData([QueueTrigger("%QueueSettings:UserDataQueue%", Connection = "QueueSettings:StorageAccount")] string queueItem, FunctionContext context)
 {
      var logger = context.GetLogger<QueueListener>();
      ... 
 }
```

Original announcement from the Microsoft DevBlog here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-the-new-azure-function-extension-libraries-beta/

also reference here:
[Azure Functions - use queue trigger with managed identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250235/azure-functions-use-queue-trigger-with-managed-identity)