# Azure Functions - use queue trigger with managed identity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to use Managed Identity with Azure Functions V3 and a QueueTrigger.
the function code is defined like this:

```
 [Function("ProcessUserData")]
 public async Task ProcessUserData([QueueTrigger("%QueueSettings:UserDataQueue%", Connection = "QueueSettings:StorageAccount")] string queueItem, FunctionContext context)
 {
      var logger = context.GetLogger<QueueListener>();
      ... 
 }
```

According to Microsoft documentation this should be possible by defining some additional configuration properties

- <CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__credential
- <CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__queueServiceUri

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#local-development-with-identity-based-connections

My local.settings.json looks like this:

```
// "QueueSettings:StorageAccount": "",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__queueServiceUri": "https://mytestfa.queue.core.windows.net/",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__credential": "managedidentity",
```

When trying to run the project locally I get the following error:

**[2021-12-06T18:07:53.181Z] The 'ProcessUserData' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessUserData'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsQueueSettings:StorageAccount' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.**

When I use and empty connection string I get another error:

```
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount": "",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__queueServiceUri": "https://mytestfa.queue.core.windows.net/",
"QueueSettings:StorageAccount__credential": "managedidentity",
```

Error:

**[2021-12-06T18:25:20.262Z] The 'ProcessUserData' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessUserData'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsQueueSettings:StorageAccount' is invalid.**

This works fine when using the full connection string with Account Key, but we have to be using managed identities.
I have upgraded to the latest version of Azure Functions Core Tole (3.0.3904) and am using Visual Studio 2022.

Additional documentation that this *should* work:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-the-new-azure-function-extension-libraries-beta/

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: [Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 'Storage' connection string is missing or empty](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/89) and [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/503163/microsoftazurewebjobshost-error-indexing-method.html)

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-functions-core-tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT yes, as noted below you need the latest beta version of the "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" package, then the error will go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by installing the 5.0.0-beta.4 version of the NuGet package "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage".

Now Managed Identify functionality is working as expected.
Hopefully this will go to GA soon.

Comment: My functions tools put this package on 4.0.4. Updating this to 5.0.0 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete:

```
"OPLRouting__credential": "managedIdentity",
```

to work with system generated identity on Event Hub