# Azure functions use-queue trigger with managed identity- Storage Queue Data Contributor Role

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-queues, queuetrigger

I am using Azure Queue Trigger v4 to get it triggered through managed identity having Storage Queue Data Contributor Role, but when new message is added in Queue, this azure function does not get triggered. I checked the application insight but there is no error.

```cs
[FunctionName("TestSyncFunction")]
    public async Task Run(
    [QueueTrigger("file-queue", Connection = "QueueConection")] QueueMessage queueMessage,
    ILogger log)
    {
      log.LogInformation($"TestSyncFunction function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
      
    }
```

//My local.settings.json looks like this:
"QueueConection__queueServiceUri": "https://xyz.queue.core.windows.net/",
"QueueConection__credential": "managedidentity"

Also, I referred to 2 existing links but there is no help at all.

[Azure Functions - use queue trigger with managed identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250235/azure-functions-use-queue-trigger-with-managed-identity)

[Azure Functions - use queue trigger with managed identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250235/azure-functions-use-queue-trigger-with-managed-identity)

Comment: on Azure portal, locally it will not work since I don't have access to managed identity.

Comment: I am using the correct queue name.

Comment: local.settings.json QueueConection":"your storageconnection string: In managed identity, we dont have to use the storageconnection string, its a direct url to your queue. refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#local-development-with-identity-based-connections

Comment: I already sent the message in Queue manually, I have done all testing but its not triggering the Azure queue function,

Comment: are you using system-assigned identity or user-assigned identity here?

Comment: yes, as described in the description, I am using managed identity having a contributor role.

Comment: have you updated the package to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.1.3`

Comment: Hope you have granted `Storage Queue Data Reader, Storage Queue Data Message Processor` RABC roles to your function app in the storage account

Comment: I have only Storage Queue Data Contributor Role access and I think this is enough to trigger the Azure Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have reproduced the issue and got the expected output using following steps-*

Primarily I updated the package to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.1.3` and then added the following roles to my function app in storage account as stated in [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=queue#tabpanel_1_queue).

[image]

[image]

Once you added these roles, then you will be able to see them in your function app as below

[image]

Then I added the below role to my account in the storage account-

[image]

*I have tested my function locally as well as in Portal and it worked as expected in both cases.*

**`Code:`**

```
public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("TestSyncFunction")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("sample-queue", Connection = "QueueConection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

**`local.setting`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "QueueConection__queueServiceUri": "https://<storageaccount name>.queue.core.windows.net/"
  }
}
```

**`Local Output:`**

[image]

**`Portal:`**

**App Settings**

[image]

**`Application Insight:`**

[image]