# "Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist." when starting Azure Function with Queue Trigger and AAD Identity

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-queues

We have an Azure Function with Queue Trigger that was working just fine until some weeks ago, when the infrastructure guys switched to AAD Identity. Ever since, we have been getting the following exception whenever the Function starts:

> Error indexing method 'MyFunctionName' Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

According to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial#edit-the-azurewebjobsstorage-configuration), the aplication setting `AzureWebJobsStorage` had to be changed to `AzureWebJobsStrorage__accountName`. This was correctly done:
[image]

However, ever since this change was applied, the exception above has been thrown.
As a workaround, we additionally re-added the old setting `AzureWebJobsStorage`, which led to the function working again.

We cannot seem to find out, where the issue lies. We have followed all the steps described in the above-mentioned tutorial, and also other solutions found in blog posts and other sites, such as adding connection names in the `[QueueTrigger]` attribute as well as local.settings.json and appsettings.json, adding `AzureWebJobsStorageAccount__credential` (with value `managedidentity`) and `AzureWebJobsStorageAccount__queueServiceUri` to the settings, and so on. Nothing seems to be helping, though.

What are we missing?
As far as I understood the tutorial, as long as the access to the storage account is granted and the setting is renamed (and its value changed, of course), all should be fine, without even needing to tough the code.

Edit:
here is the current `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your local.settings.json file?

Comment: @DasariKamali of course, I have updated the original question

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70292178/2127194) I found by chance actually solved it. Everything was set up correctly, but the library was not up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got the same error in my environment below,

[image]

I added below setting in **function app**> **Environment variables**> **App settings** as below,

> AzureWebJobsStrorage__accountName  :  <storage_name>

[image]

I switched **on** the **identity** in **function app** at Azure portal as below,

[image]

I assigned the **Storage Queue Data Contributor** role to the **function app** in the storage account at the Azure portal as below,

[image]

And, I assigned the **owner** role to the newappk AAD app in the storage account at the Azure portal as below,

[image]

**local.settings.json** :

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "QueueConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://<storage_name>.queue.core.windows.net/"
  }
}
```

**Code:**

I tried a simple queue trigger code below,

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp39
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "QueueConnection")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I added a message to the **queue** like below in the storage account at the Azure portal,

[image]

[image]

Then, I published this to function app as below,

[image]

I added the QueueConnection_queueServiceUri in the App setting below,

> QueueConnection__queueServiceUri : "https://<storage_name>.queue.core.windows.net/"

[image]

Then, I sent a message to the queue and got it triggered in Application insights as below,

[image]

I can see the message in the monitor function also as below,

[image]

Comment: We tried reproducing everything exactly as you did, but it still does not work. There were two differences:  
1. in IAM, you are assigning owner to the newappk AAD app. What exactly is newappk for?  in local.settings.json you set "QueueConnection__queueServiceUri". We did that, but then the build failed, saying it was not finding "QueueConnection" defined as Connection in the QueueTrigger. After renaming it to "QueueConnection" without the "__queueServiceUri" the build worked. However, the function app is still broken. Did we miss something?
2.

Comment: Found the issue - the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage had a version that does not support Managed Identity. (see comment in my original question with link to details)