Blob trigger Azure function in AKS with Keda
I have a Java Azure function deployed to AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) with KEDA enabled. The function uses a blob trigger, which works fine when configured with AzureWebJobsStorage set to a storage account connection string using an access key.
However, I'm trying to switch to using Managed Identity to access blob storage.
I've configured AzureWebJobsStorage with the following connection string:
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your-storage-account;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;Authentication=ManagedIdentity

When I deploy, I encounter the following error:
info: Host.Startup[0]
Job host started


fail: Host.Startup[402]
The 'BlobProcessor' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.BlobProcessor'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsStorage' is invalid.

Also tried including this configuration in different ways like below
 - name: AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri
   value : "https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net"

 - name: AzureWebJobsStorage__blobServiceUri
   value : "https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net",

None of these methods work.
How can I correctly configure Managed Identity for accessing blob storage in my Java Azure function deployed to AKS with KEDA?
adding extra code regarding my blob trigger function
@FunctionName("BlobProcessor")
    public void run(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "blobInput", path = "sonicpoccontainer/%ENV%/pxc/{name}", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") byte[] content,
        @BindingName("name") String filename,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        Logger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.info("Blob trigger function processed a blob.\n Name: " + filename + "\n Size: " + content.length + " Bytes");
        // Add your processing logic here
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ExecutionData jsonData = null;
        try {
            jsonData = objectMapper.readValue(content, ExecutionData.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        int noofrowscreated = jsonData.getNoofrowscreated();
        int noofrowsmodified = jsonData.getNoofrowsmodified();
        String dateofexecution = jsonData.getDateofexecution();
        String sourcelocation = jsonData.getSourcelocation();
        String targetlocation = jsonData.getTargetlocation();
        String user = jsonData.getUser();

        logger.info("Parsed JSON data:\n" +
            "noofrowscreated: " + noofrowscreated + "\n" +
            "noofrowsmodified: " + noofrowsmodified + "\n" +
            "dateofexecution: " + dateofexecution + "\n" +
            "sourcelocation: " + sourcelocation + "\n" +
            "targetlocation: " + targetlocation + "\n" +
            "user: " + user);







    }

error I am getting after deploying the suggested solution
enter image description here

To configure Managed Identity for accessing blob storage in your Java Azure function deployed to AKS with KEDA. Ensure that your AKS cluster has a managed identity associated with it.
az role assignment create --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" --assignee <Managed Identity Client ID> --scope /subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<Resource Group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<Storage Account Name>


In your Azure Function, update the configuration to use Managed Identity for accessing the storage account.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-function
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azure-function
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-function
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-function
        image: arkoacr1.azurecr.io/myfunctionapp:latest
        env:
        - name: AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri
          value: "https://arkostor.blob.core.windows.net"
        - name: AzureWebJobsStorage__credential
          value: "ManagedIdentity"


If you are using an application.properties file, add the following entries
AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri=https://<your-storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net
AzureWebJobsStorage__credential=ManagedIdentity

update your local.settings.json file
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri": "https://arkostor.blob.core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage__credential": "ManagedIdentity",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}



Ensure that KEDA is configured correctly and configured to scale

keda-scaled
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: blob-storage-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: azure-function
  triggers:
  - type: azure-blob
    metadata:
      blobContainerName: samples-workitems
      connectionFromEnv: AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri
      blobCount: "5"


By following these steps, you should be able to configure Managed Identity for accessing blob storage in your Java Azure function deployed to AKS with KEDA.



Hi @Arko, thanks for the answer, I did update the code as you have suggested, but I am getting
fail: Function.BlobProcessor[0]
│Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.BlobProcessor'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

I have put my blob processor code also in the question, can u explain if that need changes

Environmental variables are correctly added? Cross check using kubectl exec -it  -- printenv | grep AzureWebJobsStorage. You should see something like this- AzureWebJobsStorage__serviceUri=https://arkostor.blob.core.windows.net
AzureWebJobsStorage__credential=ManagedIdentity. If that is fine then check the connection string reference in your Java function. It should match the environment variable name.

See this Link for IAM and environment configuration from Function app perspective- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76969703/storage-account-connection-string-azurewebjobsstorage-does-not-exist-when-s

Thanks for the link, The example there is a .net application getting deployed in app service. my question is Java blob trigger azure function getting deployed in AKS with keda and how to do the connection string in the java blob trigger function.
